# How to write sql query for FIlter country as status wise

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have a simple table. I would like to end up with a table like the one given. What is the best way to write the sql statement to achieve this?

Table 1

```
 Id    Name           Approved
 1     Australia      3
 2     UAE            1
 3     India          2
```

Table 2

```
Id    Status
1     Submit
2     In-Progress
3     Pending
```

Show result as

```
Submitted    In-Progress     Pending
UAE           India         Australia
```

Comment: select MemberFirms.ID,MemberFirms.Name,Status.Name as status  from MemberFirms INNER JOIN Status On MemberFirms.StatusId =Status.ID

Comment: Maybe you should add more data so that we see what happens with, say, 10 countries.

Comment: this is a process here i create a simple countryList

Comment: Your output format is not what would typically be asked.  What is the relation between these 3 countries such that they all appear on the same line in your output?

Comment: Here i have only 2 tables table1 and table2   the table2 contained status

Comment: Hussain, Is that how you spell Australia where you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
select 
trim(replace(group_concat(submitted),',',' ')) as submitted, 
trim(replace(group_concat(InProgress),',',' ')) as InProgress,
trim(replace(group_concat(Pending),',',' ')) as Pending
from
(
Select 
case when status='Submit' then A.Name else ' ' end as submitted,
case when status='In-Progress' then A.Name else ' ' end as InProgress,
case when status='Pending' then A.Name else ' ' end as Pending

FROM

TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN
TABLE2 B
ON A.ID=B.ID
) a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below query:

```
create table #country
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(30),
    Approved int
)

create table #status
(
    ID int,
    Status varchar(30)
)

insert into #country (Name, Approved) values ('Australia',3), ('UAE',1), ('India',2)
insert into #status (ID, Status) values (1,'Submit'), (2, 'In-Progress'), (3,'Pending')

select Submit, [In-Progress],[Pending]
from (
    select t1.Name, t2.Status
    from #country t1
    inner join #status t2 on t1.Approved = t2.ID
)dd1
pivot (
    max(Name) for Status in ([Submit], [In-Progress],[Pending])
) piv

drop table #country
drop table #status
```

Output of this query:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer as of given Data:

```
select `Submit`,`In-Progress`,`Pending` from
(select `Submit`,`In-Progress`,INP.id from
(select   Name as 'Submit',a.id  from
 (select * from table1)as a

LEFT JOIN 

  (select * from table2) as b
on a.Approvide = b.`Id` 
where b.`STATUS` = 'Submit') as Sub


INNER JOIN


(select   Name as 'In-Progress',a.id  from
 (select * from table1)as a

LEFT JOIN 

  (select * from table2) as b
on a.Approvide = b.`Id` 
where b.`STATUS` = 'In-Progress') as INP
on Sub.id != INP.id) as c


INNER JOIN


(select   Name as Pending,a.id  from
 (select * from table1)as a

LEFT JOIN 

  (select * from table2) as b
on a.Approvide = b.`Id` 
where b.`STATUS` = 'Pending') as Pen

on c.id != Pen.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name,Status from Table1 natural join Table2;
```

That's simple. The result should look like this now. I think this is usual approach that how we actually retrieve the information from multiple tables.

```
Name           Status

Australia      Pending
UAE            Submit
India          In-Progress
```

Please consider